# How to get the URL parameter using Javascript in raw format

Tags: javascript

So I currently get passed a query parameter in one of my URLs on my web application. The query paramater looks like

```
https://localhost:8080/home?code=v%5E1.1%23i%5E1%23p%5E3%23I%5E3%23f%5E0%23r%5E1%23t%5EUl41XzEwOkFGNjA3MEMzMzRGOThFRTgwMkMxRUVGQjhGRUZEOTREXzJfMSNFXjI2MA%3D%3D&expires_in=299
```

I am currently parsing that code parameter using

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const code = urlParams.get('code')
    const expires_in = urlParams.get('expires_in')
```

However the parsed URLSearchParams looks like 
v^1.1#i^1#p^3#I^3#f^0#r^1#t^Ul41XzEwOkFGNjA3MEMzMzRGOThFRTgwMkMxRUVGQjhGRUZEOTREXzJfMSNFXjI2MA==

I want to use the raw code parameter seen in the URL. Is there a way to get this?

Comment: The value you've got is the actual value, the value you see in the URL is URL encoded so that special characters are interpreted correctly. If you want the raw value you should probably `encodeURIComponent(code)`

Comment: You are getting the actual, decoded URI - an example of this can be seen [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_decodeuricomponent). To get the encoded URI you can use `encodeURIComponent()` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)